# TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, if-statement

In Python when I run this piece of code I get the following exception

```
if x >=9:
    TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

---

```
from pathlib import Path
import datetime
f = open ('/Users/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.7/DAS.txt', 'r')
data=f.read()
for x in data:
    if x >=9:
        print (data)
```

The .txt file contains integer values (9,8,7,6); without including the `if` statement it prints all the values, but when I add the if it gives an exception.

How to fix it?

Comment: The text file contains characters that represent integer values.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the file contains numeric data is irrelevant - when you read it from a file it's still strings - *that happen to contain only digits*.

To obtain an integer, you have to cast the string to `int`, as in:

```
if int(x) >= 9:
    ...
```

Also, your `for` is looping over a string, so `x` are _the individual characters that make up that string. This is probably not what you want, as `int(x)` is going to break over any non-digit (such as whitespace), and even if the file was made up only of digits, then that check wouldn't make much sense (it would succeed only for `x == '9'`).

Maybe you'd want to iterate over the string split over whitespace

```
filename = '/Users/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Python 3.7/DAS.txt'
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for x in f.read().split():
        if int(x) >= 9:
            # ...
```

or directly over the lines of the file:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for x in f:
        if int(x) >= 9:
            # ...
```

(notice that I used `with` to ensure prompt closing of the file when it isn't needed anymore)

Finally, as a general bit of advice, besides the fact that production-quality scripts generally shouldn't hardcode paths, keeping data files into the Start menu directories isn't a great idea...

Comment: Would the downvoter mind to explain?